# How to calculate average price of open position of stocks Excel Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have a simple table with some dummy data to simulate stock trades. I know the its model is not exactly right, but it does comply with the basics and that's what I'm looking for.
The answer I'm looking for is how would I calculate the data on column 12. It's supposed to show the Average Price of the position at that date. If the position opened with the current row then the average price is the actual price of the trade, however the position can be increased or decreased with new prices and I want to know the average price up to that date (last two rows have this example).

Column 13 (What I got so far) has this definition*: `=SUMPRODUCT([Delta Position];--([Date Trade]<=[@[Date Trade]]);--([Position After Trade]=[@[Position After Trade]]))`
*actually the there's two more columns, Trader and Maturity Date, these two are used to filter data and are not shown to make it more readable: `--([Person]=[@Person]);--([Month]=[@month])`

(second row just shows the definition of the simpler columns)

| Date Trade | Price | op | Qty | Total | Accumulated Before | Accumulated After | Position After Trade | Qty Delta Position | Delta Position | Value of Open Position | What I got so far | Average Price Open Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 = C2 x C4 | C6 | C7 | C8 | C9 | C10 = C9 * C2 | C11 | C12 | C13 = C11 / C7 |
| 2021-12-06 | 328 | Buy | 99 | 32472 | 0 | 99 | long | 99 | 32472 | HELP: 32472 | 32472 | 328 |
| 2021-12-13 | 291 | Sell | 99 | 28809 | 99 | 0 | zero | 0 | 0 | HELP: 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-31 | 190 | Sell | 120 | 22800 | 0 | -120 | short | -120 | -22800 | HELP: -22800 | -22800 | 190 |
| 2022-02-14 | 165 | Buy | 120 | 19800 | -120 | 0 | zero | 0 | 0 | HELP: 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-04-20 | 113,7 | Sell | 200 | 22740 | 0 | -200 | short | -200 | -22740 | HELP: -22740 | -45540 | 113,7 |
| 2022-06-21 | 74,333 | Buy | 300 | 22299,9 | -200 | 100 | long | 100 | 7433,3 | HELP: 7433.3 | 39905,3 | 74,333 |
| 2022-08-16 | 86 | Buy | 50 | 4300 | 100 | 150 | long | 50 | 4300 | HELP: 11733.3 | 44205,3 | 78,222 |

Comment: Most brokerages track that for you? Edit: I could be wrong but just export your trades.

Comment: Well actually these aren't really trades, they're actually dummy trades to test out some theories about future pricing, so using a brokerage isn't really an option.

Comment: Uhh your model needs serious drastic work. Edit: how does faking trades of 50-300 predict pricing???

Comment: No no, this is just a "system" to know where the gains and losses are, the actual call for what amount to buy/sell comes from an actual model. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you think 5 = 2 * 4 as you show in the total column then I don't follow.

Comment: @SolarMike they are multiplying columns. Edit: col 5 is product of 2 and 4.

Comment: Edited to add "C" to the text of the second row, meaning Column1, Column2...

Answer (score 0):

The average price of an open position is calculated by this fórmula

[Average price fórmula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zNC.png)

Iteratively you can obtain this fórmula:

[Iterative fórmula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu6zG.png)

- First row (first operation) => Average price = M3 =  If(C3='Buy';B3;-B3)
- Second row => Average price => Average price = M4 = ((M3*F4)+(If(C4='Buy';B4*C4;-B4*C4) )) / G4
- Next rows you only have to iterate fórmula.

I hope this can help you.